# Scala: Add char after every char in List of Strings

Tags: scala, list, foreach

I have an assignment that I am having some trouble completing, using Scala. I have to define a function that returns a list of strings constructed from the list received as argument. For each letter in an element, the next character is to be added:

```
transformStrings(List("CHAT", "LIST", "ASK"))
//> res13: List[String] = List(CDHIABTU, LMIJSTT, ABSTKL)
```

So far I guess that I have to somehow map the List, and then use foreach or a for/yield to run through every char, but I'm not sure how to exactly do it.

Comment: What comes after `z` or `Z`? By ASCII value it should be `{` and `[` respectively. Do you need it to wrap around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
List("CHAT", "LIST", "ASK").map(s => s.flatMap(c => c.toString + (c+1).toChar))
// res9: List[String] = List(CDHIABTU, LMIJSTTU, ABSTKL)
```

Or:

```
List("CHAT", "LIST", "ASK").map(s => s.flatMap(c => Seq(c, (c+1).toChar)))
// res13: List[String] = List(CDHIABTU, LMIJSTTU, ABSTKL)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `foldLeft`, like:

```
List("CHAT", "LIST", "ASK").map(_.foldLeft("")((a, b) => a + b + (b + 1).toChar))
>res0: List[String] = List(CDHIABTU, LMIJSTTU, ABSTKL)
```

Explaination:

1. `a` is the **reduce value**
2. `b` is the *next char* in `String`(like "CHAT")
3. `(b+1)` means to the `next char` **ascii number**
4. `toChar` will convert the `ascii number` to `Char`
5. Finally `join` `b` and `next char` to `String`

Comment: Can you explain to a Scala newbie what the `(b + 1)` part does? is that where the character increment happens? And if so, isn't that a really strange construct? Thanks!

Comment: @patrick Each character is represented by a number because it's an ASCII value - for instance, in the Scala REPL, try entering `('C'.toInt + 1).toChar` and you'll see that you get `D`, which has an integer representation that is exactly one greater than the value of `C`.

Comment: wow, that is wild, thanks! I looked it [up](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) and was wondering whether will this work for all Unicode characters? I feel it can't return an Int for those? (Does not work for me, but might be my Terminal settings)